Messed up with python symbolic link in bin folder
problem is that I am not able to open the gnome-terminal by clicking on it icon, but I am able to use "open in terminal" from any path
Actually, I was trying to update the Python version and I manually deleted some python older version symbolic links here is the history
sudo rm python2.7 
sudo rm python3
sudo rm python3.10
sudo rm python3.10-config 
sudo rm python3-config 




Usually, trying to change the default python install of the system is a so called "fatal error": you may need to reinstall the system. To use different python versions, work with python virtual environments.
